# jquery overriding href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div (.questionsList) that contains a link. When the div is clicked, I have an element #slider that slides out. However, when the link inside the div is clicked, I want to follow that link. The problem is, when I click the link, the jquery slide effect is overriding the link href so the slider slides out and the link does nothing. How can I fix this?

This is the code I was using prior to recognizing the problem.

```
$(".questionsList").toggle(function() {       
    $('#slider').animate({ left: '375' }, 500);
}, function() {
    $('#slider').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
});
```

Comment: You should delete your question then, unless you want alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".questionsList a").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slider').click(function() {
    return false; // prevent sliding when user clicks inside the div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code:

```
$(".questionsList").toggle(function( e ) 
{       
    $('#slider').animate({ left: '375' }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
}, function( e ) 
{
    $('#slider').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```